# Returning a object created on heap by constant reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants, getter-setter

Im having a problem with returning a constant reference to an object which is created on the heap.

In my header I've defined the two heap-objects like this (using C++11 syntax)

```
private:
    Type1 *type1 = nullptr;
    Type2 *type2 = nullptr;
```

and the two getter methods like this

```
public: 
    Type1 &GetType1() const;
    Type2 &GetType2() const;
```

now in my source file i'm trying to do as follows

```
Type1 &GetType1() const
{
    return this->type1;
}

Type2 &GetType2() const
{
    return this->type2;
}
```

i've excluded checks for null and error handling for the sake of simplicity.

Now the compiler complains about

> invalid initialization of reference of type ‘type1&’ from expression
>   of type ‘type* const’

Why is it showing me that i try to convert from a constant pointer when its clearly not a constant pointer but a constant reference?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The member variable **type1** is a pointer to an object of type **Type1**. And then you try to return this _pointer_ as a reference to an _object_?

Comment: Yes, that was a misunderstanding of the concept how a reference really works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type1` is a pointer. You need to dereference it to access the object itself.

You should also decide whether you want a `const` reference (in which case the function can, and should, be `const`) or a mutable reference (in which case it can, but perhaps shouldn't, be `const`). You can provide both overloads if you like:

```
Type1 const &GetType1() const {return *type1;}
Type1       &GetType1()       {return *type1;}
```

so that the function can be used to get a modifiable reference if the object is not `const` and a read-only reference otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to override the behaviour of returning other than just dereference it? Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @SaschaMoos: I've no idea what you mean by that. The only way to access the object via a pointer is to dereference the pointer.